# ¿Cómo puedo revertir una base de datos a un punto anterior en MySql?

Tags: mysql

Buenas a todos espero que me puedan ayudar, verán lo que pasa que estoy trabajando con laravel, y no trabajo con los modelos de DB que crea, creo mis tablas en mi db. El punto es que por error mio ejecure el comando migrate:refresh teniendo los migrate de los modelos generados y me limpio toda mi DB. Existe alguna manera de regresar o revertir esos cambios en MySql?

Comment: `migrate:refresh` revierte todas las migraciones y las corre nuevamente. Pero si no usas los modelos de DB que crea y haces tus tablas propias, tendrás las mismas tal y como las creaste. Si acaso alguna se llamaba justo como las que crea Laravel, de todos modos el refresh no podría correr completo a menos que tus tablas sean idénticas a las que hubiese creado de haber usado migraciones

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que procedas a darle al comando:

`php artisan migrate: rollback` tantas veces (step) hicieste el refresh

...y para revertir todas puedes ejecutar

`php artisan migrate:reset`